# App keeps crashing. Can't find android.view.activity

Tags: android, android-activity, view, manifest

I've been making a texting app for fun, but when I started trying to remove the action title bar, the app suddenly started crashing when opened. I've looked everywhere but can't find a solution and I have no idea what the problem is. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's a [link](http://speedy.sh/RNzRH/TextEm.rar) the .rar file of my app:

**edit**: Here's what the manifest file looks like

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".ReceiveText"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SendText"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_send__text" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ChatBubble"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_chat_bubble" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Post the LogCat output from when the app crashes

Comment: how did you remove the action bar

Comment: I didn't. When I tried removing the action bar, the app started crashing so I went back and deleted everything that I just added and it still didn't work.

Comment: Please post a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example   http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Here's the log cat: Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.telephony.SmsProvider from ProcessRecord{110ff89a 31315:com.example.ben.textem/u0a324} (pid=31315, uid=10324) requires android.permission.READ_SMS or android.permission.WRITE_SMS

Answer (score 0):

put this two permission in manifest file

```
android.permission.READ_SMS
 android.permission.WRITE_SMS
```

Your manifest will look like below.

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
```

Comment: minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion will be same as you are using but add the bellow two line